# Geometric Progression in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, floating-point, string-formatting

I'm making a code for showing the 4 initial numbers of a G.P. using this code:

```
def progG(a1,q):
    return float(a1), float(a1*q), float(a1*q**2), float(a1*q**3)

def main():
    a1 = input("Informe o valor inicial de sua Progressão Geométrica: ")
    q = input("Informe a razão de sua Progressão Geométrica: ")
    print "Os 4 primeiros elementos de uma P.G. de valor inicial %.f e razão %.f são: %.f ." %(a1,q,(progG(a1,q)))
if __name__ == "__main__":      
    main()
```

When I put this to run on Shell, it makes me the two questions, but then appears this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Suzana Maria\Downloads\aula6_ex8.py", line 25, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Suzana Maria\Downloads\aula6_ex8.py", line 23, in main
    print "Os 4 primeiros elementos de uma P.G. de valor inicial %.f e razão %.f são: %.f ." %(a1,q,(progG(a1,q)))
TypeError: float argument required, not tuple
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't speak Poruguese (or is this Spanish?) but I did my best to remove your error:

```
def progG(a1,q):
    return float(a1), float(a1*q), float(a1*q**2), float(a1*q**3)

def main():
    a1 = input("Informe o valor inicial de sua Progressão Geométrica: ")
    q = input("Informe a razão de sua Progressão Geométrica: ")
    print "Os 4 primeiros elementos de uma P.G. de valor inicial %.f e razão %.f são: ." %(a1,q), (progG(a1,q))

if __name__ == "__main__":      
    main()
```

Comment: It's prtuguese, I'm brazillian. Thanks a lot for the help, it worked perfectly.

Comment: This fix works, but it's confusing to mix %-formatting and print-magic-commad this way—and of course it puts the last value after the end-of-sentence period instead of in the middle of the sentence. Better to just change the OP's last `%.f` to `%s`, which will give the same result but without screwing up the order, and be easier to understand.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your function progG(a1, q) returns a tuple - four values - not a float, but you try to print this out as a single float.

You could try:

```
geometric_string = ", ".join(["%.f" % x for x in progG(a1, q)])

print"Os 4 primeiros elementos de uma P.G. de valor inicial %.f e razão %.f são:", geometric_string
```

Comment: So, how do I fix this? I'm sorry, I don't know too much, I'm starting to take classes about Python on my college, and I've never heard of tuple.

Comment: A tuple is a collection of values, so in your case four different floating point numbers. In the above code I combine them together into one string and then print this out, formatting each float in the tuple.

Comment: This is a good explanation, but the fix doesn't work. You're leaving the first two `%.f` placeholders unreplaced. Besides the immediate `SyntaxError`, you're not feeding anything to the first two placeholders. And really, mixing %-formatting and print-magic-comma is just going to lead to confusion. Better to change the third `%.f` to `%s`, and use `% (a1, q, geometric_string)`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `%.f` requires a single float, but you're giving it four floats, wrapped up in a tuple.

You can fix this by using `%s` instead of `%.f`, because `%s` takes anything at all:

```
print "Os 4 primeiros elementos de uma P.G. de valor inicial %.f e razão %.f são: %s ." %(a1,q,(progG(a1,q)))
```

The output will be something like:

```
Os 4 primeiros elementos de uma P.G. de valor inicial 2 e razão 3 são: (2.0, 6.0, 18.0, 54.0) .
```

Notice that you have no control over how the numbers in the tuple are formatted, or how the tuple itself is formatted. So you get `2.0` instead of `2`, and you get parentheses around the whole thing, and so on.

If you want more control, you need to format things in two steps: first build a string for the tuple, then do the final formatting using that string in place of the tuple. Having total control also means you have to do a bit more work, but it's not too bad:

```
g = ", ".join("%.f" % x for x in progG(a1, q))
print "Os 4 primeiros elementos de uma P.G. de valor inicial %.f e razão %.f são: %s ." %(a1,q,g)
```

And now:

```
Os 4 primeiros elementos de uma P.G. de valor inicial 2 e razão 3 são: 2, 6, 18, 54 .
```

The first trick here is using the `join` method on strings, which takes a sequence of strings and joins them up. For example, `":".join([1, 2, 3, 4])` will give you the string `1:2:3:4`. The second trick is using a comprehension to map each member of the tuple into something different—in this case, map each float `x` into the string `"%.f" % x`.